# c# Linq ForEach

Tags: c#, linq

Хочу немного отрефакторить код, подскажите, как можно переписать такую запись?

```
var result = new List<string>();        
foreach (var value in values)
{
   if (!childrens.Any(i => value == i.Name))
   {
      result.Add(value);
   }
}
```

Какой записи я хочу добиться:

```
var result = values
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(x => ???)
```

Есть ли возможность вообще переписать это с помощью ForEach? Заранее всем спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не надо `ForEach`:

```cs
result = values.Where(value => !childrens.Any(i => value == i.Name)).ToList();
```

Хотя можно ещё оптимизировать как-то так, если `values` уникальные и порядок их следования не важен:

```cs
children_names = childrens.Select(i => i.Name).ToHashSet()
result = values.ToHashSet().ExceptWith(children_names).ToList();
```

А если не уникальные и/или важен порядок, то можно просто использовать `HashSet` для проверки вхождения, всё-равно будет возможно быстрее в каких-то случаях, чем гонять `Any` на каждый элемент:

```cs
children_names = childrens.Select(i => i.Name).ToHashSet()
result = values.Where(value => !children_names.Contains(value)).ToList();
```

Comment: Вы правы, действительно, зачем мне там ForEach :) Спасибо за оба варианта!

Comment: Пришлось только исправлять на ходу, пару лет на `C#` не писал, стал уже забывать ))